# Asymptote: buildcycle for concentric figures

Tags: asymptote

The following code producdes the first attached picture:

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
unitsize(1cm);

import graph;

path Ellipse(pair centre = (0,0), real xradius, real yradius){
    return shift( ( centre ) )*scale( xradius, yradius )*Circle( (0,0), 1);
}

real step = 1.4, height = 1.3;

guide U = Circle( (0,0), 1), E = Ellipse( (0,0), 1.3, 0.6 ), B = box( (-1.2, -0.5), (1.2,0.5) ), Bo = box( (-0.4, -1.2), (0.4,1.2) ), all[] = U ^^ E ^^ B ^^ Bo;

draw( (-step,0) -- (2.2*1.5step,0), invisible );
draw( (0,-height) -- (0,height), invisible );

draw(all);

guide g = all[0];

for(int k = 1; k < all.length; ++k){
    g = buildcycle(g, all[k]);
}

draw(shift(2.2step)*g);
```

What I actually want to draw is precisely the border of the 4 paths, as in the second attached picture (done with Inkscape); I followed the instructions given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141192/11438); there, the figures are not concentric and perphaps that is why the final path obtained is the one given there.

How can I obtain the border of the four figures as in the second picture? Thanks!

[image: Asymptote result]
[image: Desired image]

Comment: I am assuming that you won't be excited about "fill all the paths white" answers, right? ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: it would be certainly a solution, but one which furnishes me no new knowledge ;)

Comment: Both proposed answers are simple and useful! I'd really like seeing a solution involving the `buildcyle` function, though.

Comment: It seems that `buildcycle` is not working when there are 3 ou more intersections points.

Comment: Having `E` (and `all`) as variable names should be avoided since `E` is defined as east (-1,0).

Comment: @O.G.: is there a bug report on `buildcycle` about this?

Comment: I marked James' post as the answer, just to have one! I very much hope more people will contribute! Thank you all!

Comment: @ÓscarGuajardo I think that `buildcycle` is ok and making a very general routine is difficult. Here your paths are cyclic and you have more 4 intersections points. You can observe the code of buildcycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is a more automated version of the answer from @chishimotoji.  My code breaks all the paths up into subpaths and then automatically determines which should be plotted using `inside(path p, pair z)` functions.

I created the `isOutside` and `getOuterSubpaths` functions as defined below.  Using these functions, you will only need to define the paths, sends them to the functions, and draw the subpaths that are returned.

One advantage of this automation is that the code does not expand exponentially as more paths are added, as shown in the figure at the right.

I've only tested this code with the paths as shown below.

[image: Sample Code Output]

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
unitsize(1inch);

bool isOutside(pair p, path[] paths)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; ++i)
    {
        if (inside(paths[i], p)) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}

path[] getOuterSubpaths(path[] ps)
{
    path[] subpaths;
    for (int i = 0; i < ps.length; ++i)
    {
        path[] otherPaths;
        real[] times = { 0.0};
        for (int j = 0; j < ps.length; ++j)
        {
            if (j == i) { continue; }
            otherPaths.push(ps[j]);
            real[][] newTimes = intersections(ps[i], ps[j]);
            for (int k = 0; k < newTimes.length; ++k)
            {
                times.push(newTimes[k][0]);
            }
        }
        times.push(size(ps[i]));
        times = sort(times);
        for (int j = 1; j < times.length; ++j)
        {
            real thisTime = times[j];
            real lastTime = times[j-1];
            real midTime = (thisTime + lastTime) / 2.0;
            pair midLocation = point(ps[i], midTime);
            if (isOutside(midLocation, otherPaths))
            {
                subpaths.push(subpath(ps[i], lastTime, thisTime));
            }
        }
    }
    return subpaths;
}

path[] startPaths;
startPaths.push(unitcircle);
startPaths.push(scale(1.3,0.6)*unitcircle);
startPaths.push(scale(2.4,1.0)*shift(-0.5,-0.5)*unitsquare);
startPaths.push(scale(0.8,2.4)*shift(-0.5,-0.5)*unitsquare);
draw(startPaths);

path[] outerSubpaths = getOuterSubpaths(startPaths);
draw(outerSubpaths, 4+red);

startPaths.push(rotate(45)*scale(1.4,0.2)*unitcircle);
startPaths.push(rotate(135)*scale(1.4,0.2)*unitcircle);
draw(shift(3.0,0)*startPaths);
path[] outerSubpaths = getOuterSubpaths(startPaths);
draw(shift(3.0,0)*outerSubpaths, 4+red);
```

Comment: Fascinating! I've a question about your boolean function: why do you have `return true` after the loop? Wouldn't that always return `true`?

Comment: @ÓscarGuajardo: Thank you.  the loop in the boolean function is checking to see if the point p is inside any of your original paths.  If it is, then the function returns `false` and the `return true;` line is never reached.

Comment: Great ! very interesting code

Answer (score 5):

This is raw code! Clean code should be written by yourself.

```
unitsize(1cm);
guide U = circle( (0,0), 1), 
      E = ellipse( (0,0), 1.3, 0.6 ), 
      B = box( (-1.2, -0.5), (1.2,0.5) ), 
      Bo = box( (-0.4, -1.2), (0.4,1.2) ), 
      all[] = U ^^ E ^^ B ^^ Bo;
pair[] Int=intersectionpoints(U,Bo);
pair[] Intt=intersectionpoints(U,B);
pair[] IntT=intersectionpoints(E,B);
real[][] Intr=intersections(U,Bo);
real[][] Inttr=intersections(U,B);
real[][] IntTr=intersections(E,B);

draw(Int[0]--max(Bo)--(xpart(min(Bo)),max(Bo).y)--Int[1],dashed+red);
draw(subpath(U,Intr[1][0],Inttr[1][0]),dashed+purple);
draw(Intt[1]--(min(B).x,max(B).y)--IntT[3],blue+dashed);
draw(subpath(E,IntTr[3][0],IntTr[4][0]),gray+dashed);
draw(IntT[4]--min(B)--Intt[2],cyan+dashed);
draw(subpath(U,Inttr[2][0],Intr[2][0]),magenta+dashed);
draw(Int[2]--min(Bo)--(max(Bo).x,min(Bo).y)--Int[3],dashed);
draw(subpath(U,Intr[3][0],Inttr[3][0]),magenta+dashed);
draw(Intt[3]--(max(B).x,min(B).y)--IntT[7],dashed);

path knight=(max(B).x,min(B).y)--max(B);
path m1=cut(E,knight,0).before,m2=cut(E,knight,1).after;
draw(m2^^m1,green);

draw(IntT[0]--max(B)--Intt[0],dashed);
draw(subpath(U,Inttr[0][0],Intr[0][0]),dashed+orange);
shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful approach! Thanks! What did you mean by "raw code" and "clean code"?

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=838CC6AC8CB0D8DDB98FDB1AE0C8A443)

Answer (score 3):

One can plot this very easily if one knows the polar coordinate representations of the rectangle and ellipse. Here is the asymptote code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
import graph;
size(8cm,0);

real rrect(real a,real b,real t) { 
    return 1/max(abs(cos(t)/a),abs(sin(t)/b)); };

real relli(real a,real b,real t) { 
    return  a*b/sqrt((b*cos(t))**2+(a*sin(t))**2);};

real rrr(real t) {real [] tmp={relli(1.3,0.6,t),rrect(1.2,0.5,t),rrect(0.5,1.2,t),1};
return max(tmp);};

pair f(real t) { return (rrr(t)*cos(t),rrr(t)*sin(t)); }

draw(graph(f, 0, 2*pi, n=721), thick());

\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the explanations, let me switch to Ti*k*Z with which I am more familiar.

A rectangle width `\a` and height `\b` has the polar representation (called `rrect` in the asymptote code)

```
Rplane(\a,\b,\t)=1/max(abs(cos(\t)/\a),abs(sin(\t)/\b));
```

where `\t` is the angle, as illustrated in

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
    Rplane(\a,\b,\t)=1/max(abs(cos(\t)/\a),abs(sin(\t)/\b));}]
 \begin{scope}
  \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,samples=361]
  (\t:{Rplane(1.2,0.5,\t)});    
  \draw[red,dashed] (-1.2,-0.5) rectangle (1.2,0.5);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
  \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,samples=361]
  (\t:{Rplane(0.5,1.2,\t)});    
  \draw[red,dashed] (-0.5,-1.2) rectangle (0.5,1.2);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An ellipse has the representation (called `relli` in the asymptote code)

```
Rellipse(\a,\b,\t)=\a*\b/sqrt(pow(\b*cos(\t),2)+pow(\a*sin(\t),2));
```

as illustrated in

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
    Rellipse(\a,\b,\t)=\a*\b/sqrt(pow(\b*cos(\t),2)+pow(\a*sin(\t),2));}]
 \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,samples=361]
 (\t:{Rellipse(1.3,0.6,\t)});   
 \draw[cyan,dashed] (0,0) circle[x radius=1.3,y radius=0.6];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So all one needs to do is to plot the maximum of the radius function of the rectangles, ellipse and circle, for which it is just a constant radius.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
    Rplane(\a,\b,\t)=1/max(abs(cos(\t)/\a),abs(sin(\t)/\b));
    Rellipse(\a,\b,\t)=\a*\b/sqrt(pow(\b*cos(\t),2)+pow(\a*sin(\t),2));}]
 \draw[very thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,samples=361]
 (\t:{max(Rplane(1.2,0.5,\t),Rplane(0.5,1.2,\t),Rellipse(1.3,0.6,\t),1)});  
 \draw[red,densely dashed] (-1.2,-0.5) rectangle (1.2,0.5);
 \draw[orange,densely dashed] (-0.5,-1.2) rectangle (0.5,1.2);
 \draw[blue,densely dashed] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
 \draw[cyan,densely dashed] (0,0) circle[x radius=1.3,y radius=0.6]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The TikZ solution is very neat! Thanks!